# Chrome extension with DB sql query in cloud

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, google-chrome-extension, cloud

We want to develop an application with a Google Chrome extension that will have to do a query-intensive databases that will be in a cloud service. I have the following questions:

a) Can it be done with javascript from the Chrome extension?
b) I understand that I have to have a layer of application logic, such as MVC controller. What other options are there and which one is better?
c) What cloud service is the most recommended (Oracle, Azure, Rackspace, etc ...), taking into account that it is important the speed of response?
d) The advice and response format is json?

thanks

Comment: AJAX request can be sent from within a Chrome extension, hope that helps in a) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** Yes, it can be done with JavaScript, you'd be sending an AJAX request to your server on the cloud and returning the response.

**b)** Which one is better will likely solicit debate, the best is if you check the options and decide which is better for yourself in your particular use case. [Here is a comparison of all(most)](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) MV* JavaScript frameworks to get you started.

**c)** All of the cloud services have advantages and disadvantages. I worked with Azure and Heroku and was successful. It depends on your need, what server side language are you using?

**d)** The data exchange for your response doesn't really matter. JSON, XML, SEN whatever. JSON is very standard which is a big pro for it, but data-exchange can be accomplished by any data-exchange format.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding point b), the question I have is about what options I have for application logic. That is, I have a chrome extension that sends a query (get) and what is the best way to process it? Web Application?? Does Web Service? MVC?? Servlets?? In that I can set to decide. thanks

Comment: MVC is a design pattern to organize your server-side application logic. Servlets are a Java term. What server-side logic do you know? You can use node.js (server side JavaScript) and share code between the client and server side

Comment: inglésespañolfrancés
Thank you. I want to use the most appropriate server logic for a query sent by a term extension chrome (I guess with a get request from javascript) and return results in a DB consultation cloud, in principle in json format. Which option is best suited for it? MVC. Net? Java Servlets? Node.js?